# Wagtail: Edit handling of GeoJSON field in a snippet vs. Page model

Tags: python, django, wagtail, django-leaflet

I am trying to implement [Django Leaflet](https://django-leaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) into my Wagtail app. The underlying form field is a [GeoJSON](https://django-geojson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html) field. I only get it to work properly when registering my model **as a snippet** not as a `Page` model, though.

I can add instances of my model based on the `Page` model and the GeoJSON value is written correctly to the database. I can also edit a features geometry **but** the geometry won't be displayed on the leaflet map. When Wagtail renders the edit view for the `Page` based model the GeoJSON turns into a string and deserialization fails:

```
Error creating geometry from value
'"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-322.276779,59.41526]}"'
(String input unrecognized as WKT EWKT, and HEXEWKB.)
```

Loading the edit view for the same model registered as a snippet works, the JSON stays a `dict` and the geometry gets rendered on the leaflet map. So I suspect somewhere Wagtails edit handler does something to the `context` it doesn't do when handling snippets. Where to look and how to prevent it?

Comment: Hi John. It might help if you add some of your template and models code to the question. This way it will be easier to investigate.

Comment: Hey. I know, the question is a bit too abstract, but I didn’t really know how and where to concrete it. I found a solution though and posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I followed the error message to it’s method and overwrote it. My widget looks like this now:

```
[...]
from leaflet.forms.widgets import LeafletWidget

class LeafletWidgetWithMedia(LeafletWidget):
    include_media = True
    template_name = "widget.html"

    def deserialize(self, value):
        try:
            value = json.loads(value)  # this is the part I added
            return GEOSGeometry(value)
        except (GEOSException, ValueError, TypeError) as err:
            logger.error("Error creating geometry from value '%s' (%s)", value, err)
        return None
```

I am still curious though what happens internally on Wagtails side.